# Do I get my passport back while my German Blue Card is being processed?

Tags: europe

I plan on initiating my German Blue Card application from the US. However, one of the required documents at my appointment at the German Consulate in Chicago is my current passport. Will I get my passport back after my appointment at the consulate so I can continue traveling to other countries for vacation while my Blue card is being processed, or will I be "grounded" during the 1-3 months it takes to process my Blue Card?